# Какую среду выбрать для разработки приложения на ios?

Tags: ios, мобильные-приложения

столкнулся с некой проблемой ( незнание данной области ). Мне нужно перенести сайт написанный на html+css+php+js на приложение ios. Грубо говоря, нужно написать приложение, как сайт. Я разумеется погуглил и получил довольно много информации, но все советуют писать приложения для ios на макинтошах, к несчастью у меня windows. Какую среду для разработки следует выбрать? На каких языках лучше реализовывать поставленную задачу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034225/swift-coding-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: в свое время у меня была виртуалка с mac os, среда Xcode

Comment: @azlov порылся и нашел Flash CS5, он подойдет для поставленной задачи?

Comment: выдержка из интернета "Adobe Flash CS5 Professional – это одна из самых мощных и популярных программ, которая предназначена для профессиональной разработки интерактивных флэш-роликов или интерактивного содержимого веб-страничек, а также для создания видео-флешроликов."

Comment: Учтите, что у  Apple своя экосистема со своими языками: Objective-C или Swift

Comment: Знаете, посмотрела в интернете и правда можно писать ios приложения на Flash CS5

Comment: @azlov Порылся еще лучше, Visual studio предлагает какой-то "мост" для написания приложений под ios, не знаю насколько это удобно, но стоит попытаться

https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/bridges/ios/